# How should I deal with the compiler warning for an Task-returning interface method that doesn't require await?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an interface which will be implemented by multiple classes.  The interface has a method that requires asynchronous calls with some implementations, but does not require asynchronous calls with the others.  It looks something like this:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
   Task DoTheThing();
}

public class DoSomethingOnTheWeb : IDoSomething
{
   public async Task DoTheThing()
   {
      // Do something that requires an async method, such as HttpClient.PostAsync()
   }
}

public class DoSomethingLocally : IDoSomething
{
   public async Task DoTheThing() 
   {
      // Everything in this method can be done synchronously
   }
}
```

`DoSomethingLocally.DoTheThing` doesn't have any `await` calls in it, so Visual Studio gives me a warning that I'm not `await`ing anything inside an `async` method.  Is there a clean way of handling this situation without either disabling the compiler warning or adding `Task.Delay(0)` to the method?

Comment: Remove `async` keyword and return `Task.CompletedTask`

Comment: @JohanP Thank you, I didn't know about `Task.CompletedTask`

Comment: You can also retain the `async` keyword, and add an `await Task.CompletedTask` anywhere inside the method to prevent the warning from appearing. This way you'll get the familiar async exception behavior: calling the method never throws, exceptions are emerged on `await`.